# Memory leaks with Intel MKL SPBLAS

Tags: memory-leaks, fortran, sparse-matrix, heap-memory, intel-mkl

I'm trying to use the Intel MKL Inspector/Executor Sparse BLAS library and I've been struggling with faulty memory use in the `mkl_sparse_convert_csr` subroutine. The simple program below can reproduce my problem:

```
program debug
use mkl_spblas
use omp_lib
use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only: c_int, c_double
implicit none
integer, parameter :: DIM = 10000
integer :: stat, i
integer(kind = c_int), dimension(DIM) :: irn, jcn
real(kind = c_double), dimension(DIM) :: val
type(sparse_matrix_t) :: mat1, mat2

do i = 1, DIM
  irn(i) = i
  jcn(i) = i
  val(i) = 1.0d0
end do

call omp_set_num_threads(1)
stat = mkl_sparse_d_create_coo (A = mat1, indexing = SPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ONE, &
  rows = DIM, cols = DIM, nnz = DIM, row_indx = irn, col_indx = jcn, values = val)
if (stat /= 0) stop 'Error in mkl_sparse_d_create_coo'

stat = mkl_sparse_convert_csr (source = mat1, &
  operation = SPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, dest = mat2)
if (stat /= 0) stop 'Error in mkl_sparse_convert_csr'

stat = mkl_sparse_destroy (A = mat1)
if (stat /= 0) stop 'Error in mkl_sparse_destroy (mat1)'

stat = mkl_sparse_destroy (A = mat2)
if (stat /= 0) stop 'Error in mkl_sparse_destroy (mat2)'

call mkl_free_buffers
end program debug
```

When I check with Valgrind I get the following report of memory leaks:

```
==27267== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==27267== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==27267== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==27267== Command: ../bin/LINKS_debug
==27267== 
==27267== 
==27267== HEAP SUMMARY:
==27267==     in use at exit: 495 bytes in 6 blocks
==27267==   total heap usage: 47 allocs, 41 frees, 463,031 bytes allocated
==27267== 
==27267== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 6
==27267==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27267==    by 0x504CA98: gomp_malloc (alloc.c:37)
==27267==    by 0x505BA56: gomp_init_num_threads (proc.c:91)
==27267==    by 0x504B06A: initialize_env (env.c:1244)
==27267==    by 0x4010732: call_init (dl-init.c:72)
==27267==    by 0x4010732: _dl_init (dl-init.c:119)
==27267==    by 0x40010C9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so)
==27267== 
==27267== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 6
==27267==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27267==    by 0x152F22: mkl_serv_malloc (in /home/rcarvalho/repos/debug/bin/LINKS_debug)
==27267==    by 0x1261B4: mkl_sparse_d_create_coo_i4_avx2 (in /home/rcarvalho/repos/debug/bin/LINKS_debug)
==27267==    by 0x112AF8: MAIN__ (main.f90:49)
==27267==    by 0x112C07: main (main.f90:31)
==27267== 
==27267== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 6
==27267==    at 0x4C31B25: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27267==    by 0x590C7E4: _dlerror_run (dlerror.c:140)
==27267==    by 0x590C050: dlopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (dlopen.c:87)
==27267==    by 0x150F32: mkl_serv_inspector_suppress (in /home/rcarvalho/repos/debug/bin/LINKS_debug)
==27267==    by 0x150E8C: mkl_serv_lock (in /home/rcarvalho/repos/debug/bin/LINKS_debug)
==27267==    by 0x14EFA1: mkl_serv_cpu_detect (in /home/rcarvalho/repos/debug/bin/LINKS_debug)
==27267==    by 0x112EC4: mkl_sparse_d_create_coo_i4 (in /home/rcarvalho/repos/debug/bin/LINKS_debug)
==27267==    by 0x112AF8: MAIN__ (main.f90:49)
==27267==    by 0x112C07: main (main.f90:31)
==27267== 
==27267== 47 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 6
==27267==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27267==    by 0x4017880: _dl_exception_create (dl-exception.c:77)
==27267==    by 0x6996250: _dl_signal_error (dl-error-skeleton.c:117)
==27267==    by 0x4009812: _dl_map_object (dl-load.c:2384)
==27267==    by 0x4014EE3: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:235)
==27267==    by 0x69962DE: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:196)
==27267==    by 0x40147C9: _dl_open (dl-open.c:605)
==27267==    by 0x590BF95: dlopen_doit (dlopen.c:66)
==27267==    by 0x69962DE: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:196)
==27267==    by 0x699636E: _dl_catch_error (dl-error-skeleton.c:215)
==27267==    by 0x590C734: _dlerror_run (dlerror.c:162)
==27267==    by 0x590C050: dlopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (dlopen.c:87)
==27267== 
==27267== 192 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 5 of 6
==27267==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27267==    by 0x504CA98: gomp_malloc (alloc.c:37)
==27267==    by 0x5059B65: gomp_get_thread_pool (pool.h:42)
==27267==    by 0x5059B65: get_last_team (team.c:146)
==27267==    by 0x5059B65: gomp_new_team (team.c:165)
==27267==    by 0x5050DDB: GOMP_parallel_start (parallel.c:126)
==27267==    by 0x17D0A4: mkl_sparse_d_coo_csr_new_omp_i4 (in /home/rcarvalho/repos/debug/bin/LINKS_debug)
==27267==    by 0x17D4A7: mkl_sparse_d_convert_coo_to_csr_i4 (in /home/rcarvalho/repos/debug/bin/LINKS_debug)
==27267==    by 0x17D554: mkl_sparse_d_export_csr_data_i4 (in /home/rcarvalho/repos/debug/bin/LINKS_debug)
==27267==    by 0x126E68: mkl_sparse_d_convert_csr_i4_avx2 (in /home/rcarvalho/repos/debug/bin/LINKS_debug)
==27267==    by 0x112B38: MAIN__ (main.f90:52)
==27267==    by 0x112C07: main (main.f90:31)
==27267== 
==27267== 208 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 6 of 6
==27267==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27267==    by 0x504CA98: gomp_malloc (alloc.c:37)
==27267==    by 0x505AFFA: gomp_new_icv (team.c:968)
==27267==    by 0x504CF24: omp_set_num_threads (libgomp.h:681)
==27267==    by 0x112AB3: MAIN__ (main.f90:47)
==27267==    by 0x112C07: main (main.f90:31)
==27267== 
==27267== LEAK SUMMARY:
==27267==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27267==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27267==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27267==    still reachable: 495 bytes in 6 blocks
==27267==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27267== 
==27267== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==27267== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

It seems that this kind of problem has been also reported before and, as suggested in [MKL Sparse BLAS segfault when transposing CSR with 100M rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37395541/mkl-sparse-blas-segfault-when-transposing-csr-with-100m-rows), I'm already setting the number of threads to 1 and also using the `call mkl_free_buffers` subroutine. However, the problem is still there and, in a bigger project I have, this memory leak leads leads to a program crash due to invalid writes. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: I would suggest contacting the official support forum where the Intel engineers are more likely to read it.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the problem with the latest 2019 u4 version of mkl and with Intel Inspector tool for checking the mem leaks.

> I compiled the test as follows: 
>           ifort -g -mkl mkl_spblas.f90 test_memleak.f90
>   running the inspector to get memory analysis like as follows:
>   **inspxe-cl -collect mi1 ./a.out**

Collection started. To stop the collection, either press CTRL-C or enter from another console window: inspxe-cl -r /nfs/home/gfedorov/_work/_Stakoverflow/55630336/r000mi1 -command stop.
Intel(R) Math Kernel Library Version 2019.0.4 Product Build 20190411 for Intel(R) 64 architecture applications

**0 new problem(s) found**

Comment: The problem was detected with valgrind